# What's the meaning of the caret character on the very beginning of sha1 of commit in the git-blame

Tags: git

In git-blame, we usually see lines in a file like below:

f9a0a430 (Owen Lin         2011-08-17 22:07:43 +0800   1)

The first column is the sha1 which represents the commit of last modified.
But sometimes it looks like this:

^f9a0a43 (Owen Lin         2011-08-17 22:07:43 +0800   1)

What is the meaning of the caret character on the very left of the first column?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The caret (`^`) appears when you do `git blame` with a range of commits. The caret appears on lines that were last modified before the first commit of the range.

For example, running `git blame HEAD.. file` will show the caret on every line, since the lines have not been changed since `HEAD` (the latest commit).

Another example: `git blame HEAD^.. file` will show the caret on all the lines except the ones that were modified in the last commit.